# Adding a hidden form field to a dynamically generated Squarespace newsletter block using JS

Tags: javascript, mailchimp, squarespace

I'm trying to add a hidden field to my homepage newsletter signup at http://greig.cc/ so that I can track the signup source in Mailchimp.

This is the code that I'm injecting into the page, but it throws an 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' error and I can't work out why.

Is it something to do with the fact that the rest of the form is rendered after the page is loaded? (this is why I'm using the class name to target the form).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var formcontainer = document.getElementsByClassName('newsletter-form');
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'hidden';
input.name = 'SOURCE';
input.id = 'SOURCE';
input.value = 'homepage';
formcontainer.appendChild(input);
</script>
```

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed my doing two things :)

(1) Waiting for the DOM to load before running the script
(2) Iterating through getElementsByClassName to get the first item in the array. {Not bothering to loop through this as I only have 1 form per page}

```
<script language="JavaScript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", theDomHasLoaded, false); 
function theDomHasLoaded(e) {
  var formelements = document.getElementsByClassName('newsletter-form');
  formelements[0].innerHTML += "<input name='SOURCE' id='SOURCE' type='hidden' value='homepage' />";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so `formcontainer` contains an array of elements (even if there is only one matching element).

It's likely that `formcontainer.appendChild(input)` is failing because the `formcontainer` array won't have a function called `appendInput`.

Try changing the line `formcontainer.appendChild(input);` to read `formcontainer[0].appendChild(input);` and see if that fixes the error.

You can also set a breakpoint in the code using Chrome's Inspector or the Firefox dev tools. To debug an error like this I'd suggest putting the breakpoint on the very first line of your code, and stepping through one line at a time until the error occurs. That'll narrow it down to a single line so you're not looking for a needle in a haystack :)

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately I still get the same errors. Breakpoints have always mystified me, will try that out :)

Answer (score -1):

Just do it the simple way, and add the hidden field right to the form with HTML:

`<input type="hidden" value="homepage" />`

If for some reason you have to use JavaScript, put this script right before the closing `</head>` tag:

```
<script language="JavaScript">  document.getElementById('newsletter-form').innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='homepage' />";
</script>
```

Also, add the `id="newsletter-form"` attribute to your `<form>` tag.

This will add the specified HTML code to your form with the specified `id`.

I hope I helped you :)

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is that I don't have any direct control over the contents of the form... it is generated using a script by Squarespace. Any idea how I can add the id? Or target the class of the form instead?

Comment: ` <form class="newsletter-form" autocomplete="on" method="POST" onsubmit="return (function(form) { Y.use
  ('squarespace-form-submit', 'node',
  function (Y) { (new Y.Squarespace.FormSubmit({ formNode: Y.Node(form) })).submit('539d9dcfe4b0990491b0500d', '') }); return false;})(this)">`